# Why is my MVC route not being found when I upload a large file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I am using attribute routing for an MVC 5.2.3 project, and have run across a weird issue.

Users are able to upload files to the site, with a maximum file size of 3 MB. This functionality was and is working just fine. Recently, though, I realized that the size limit was only being enforced via JavaScript. So, I added some handling to check the size server-side before saving the file. I then removed the restriction on the front end, and uploaded a 5.26 MB file to test. To my relief, the upload was blocked. To my horror though, the response wasn't my nicely formatted error message, it was a 404.

Debugging with IIS Express, I found that for large files, the request doesn't even make it to the action.
On the other hand, uploading small files (tested up to 800KB) still works as expected. I can even decrease my coded-in limit to 1 KB, and successfully block my 800KB files with my nice error message.

Default IIS max request length seems to be about 30 MB. I tried upping that regardless, but no luck. I looked into the jQuery file upload library we use, but that supports files up to 4GB. I also tried recording the request with Fiddler, but couldn't find any obvious reasons for the larger one to fail. I also tried recording a successful file submission, and then replaying it with Fiddler's composer feature, replacing the file with the larger one. I got 404. One final oddity I haven't been able to explain, when looking at the Network tab in Firefox dev tools for a successful request, the Type column will be JSON. Failed/large requests show XML instead.

Why is my routing failing ONLY for large files?

Comment: Show us how you limited the file size.

Comment: And; do you have a custom action filter or error page kicking in? (which might cause the 404?)

Comment: It is because there are default limitations you have to change. https://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @jgauffin I did a pretty simple check: file.ContentLength > 3000000. I really don't think that's the issue though; submitting small files with that check in place works, and if I lower 3000000 to say, 30, my small testing files are blocked with my error message

Comment: @Stefan No, the only routes are the Attribute routes and a default route pointing to a home page

Answer (score 2):

Check out `maxAllowedCOntentLength` setting in web.config under `system.webServer`and set a max value you need (value in bytes):

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: MaxAllowedContentLength is the same as the IIS setting I mentioned in my post. It defaults to 30 MB, and increasing it to 3 GB didn't help

Comment: setting in web.config of your application has higher priority than IIS setting. Is it possible that you are changing IIS setting instead of app's web.config?

Comment: The IIS settings read from and write to the web.config file. I did make the change in IIS, but doing so made the exact snippet you have in your answer show up in my web.config

Comment: Would this explain the 404?

Comment: Found it! That particular setting wasn't it, but you got me on the right path. Thanks Roman!

Answer (score 0):

Roman.Pavelko's answer didn't end up being the issue, but it did get me on the right path.

There is another setting you can apply in the web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxx" />
</system.web>
```

This value defaults to 4MB (in bytes). After upping it to 50MB, everything works like a charm!